# Ho to correctly use torchvision.ops.generalized_box_iou_loss?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, pytorch-lightning

I’m training a model to fit bounding boxes on images. All Bounding boxes are defined by two coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2). To fit these bounding boxes I first used mse_loss. The loss converges, but the results are still not great enough.
I therefore tried to use [generalized_box_iou_loss](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.ops.generalized_box_iou_loss.html) with reduction='mean' (to have a Scalar for back-propagation). My bounding boxes satisfy the requirements 0 <= x1 < x2 and 0 <= y1 < y2. However, the loss is only approaching 1.

The final layer of the model looks like this.

```
self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 4)
...
# in forward:
x = self.fc3(x)
```

And the training step is defined as follows:

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    y_hat = self.model(x_aug) 
    loss = generalized_box_iou_loss(y_hat, y, reduction='mean')
    self.log("train_loss", loss)
    return loss
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?
Best, Jona

Comment: please could you share complete code for your network and how you are computing the predictions and losses. I was running into the same issue myself and I tracked it down to a bug in the way I was computing the loss.